# How to make css and js file in vue project work in production with nginx

Tags: vue.js, nginx

I've Vue project here is my path vue in Ubuntu 18.04

```
/var/www/html/vue/{ project here }
```

the problem is my css path are `/css` which refer to `/var/www/html/css` 
How to set up my css in vue project refer in folder here is my nginx setup

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location /vue {
        // I try to make root path but It's not workking error 500 when I uncomment #root
           #root /var/www/html/vue;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /vue/index.html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following with your current config:

```
 location /css {
    alias /var/www/html/css;
 }
```